# Looking for HP driver package sp42635 for Pavilion laptop

Tags: drivers, hp-pavilion

I'm desperately looking for this NVidia driver package for HP Pavilion. I have tried numerous ways of downloading the driver from HP, to no avail, so I'm hoping someone somewhere has the file and can send it to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Super User is not set up to operate in that way.

Answer (score 2):

I was successfully able to DL it from HP's public FTP server at http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp42501-43000/.  If you can't browse, the ftp directory, try a direct link: http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp42501-43000/sp42635.exe

This version of the file is dated 4/28/09.

Comment: if you still can't download them, check the link of the website I postet a few minutes before. (not the hp-website...)

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Display-and-video/NVidia-Drivers-Download-Corrupted/m-p/60768

if you scroll down at this page to [this comment from 04-27-2009 05:25 PM](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video/NVidia-Drivers-Download-Corrupted/m-p/60854/highlight/true#M2580) then you will find a working link-list.